# PHP remove entire word from string if contains

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have code that displays my tweets. In the tweet the pictures are showing up as urls as are the links. I would like to remove the entire 'WORD' if it is a pic or a link. PS I found threads on here that are close to what I am looking for but do not produce my desired effect.

If it contains a "http" or a ".pic" I then want to remove the entire 'word'.

Here is my code:

```
<?php


$wordlist = array('http','pic');
 $replaceWith  = "";

/* Sample data */
$words = 'This tweet has a pic.twitter.com/00GeQ3zLub and a url http://www.mywebsite.com';

foreach ($wordlist as $v)
  $words = clean($v, $words, $replaceWith);

function clean($word, $value, $replaceWith) {
    return preg_replace("/\w*$word\w*/i", "$replaceWith ",trim($value));
}

echo $words;
?>
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**: This tweet has a .twitter.com/00GeQ3zLub and a url ://www.mywebsite.com

**DESIRED RESULT**: This tweet has a and a url

UPDATE for clarification:
I want to remove any "string of characters with no spaces" that contain a ".pic" or a "http". I don't know how to explain it with the right terms... but if a .pic.twitter.com/ia8akd is in my tweet I want the whole thing gone. Same with anything that contains a "http". I want the WHOLE 'string' gone. for example my tweet is "This is my website: http://www.MyWebsite.com. Pretty cool?" I would like this to display as "This is my website:  Pretty cool?"

Comment: you mean you want to get 
from $words ?

Comment: pic.tw itter.com/00GeQ3zLub

Comment: I want to remove any "string of characters with no spaces" that contain a ".pic" or a "http".  I don't know how to explain it with the right terms... but I want to remove anything that contains a ".pic" or a "http".

Comment: Try `\S` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\w` does not match a `.`, nor `:`. You should match all continuos non-whitespace characters around your words.

```
\S*(?:http|pic)\S*
```

This will remove anything starting with `pic` though, it is not specific to a URL.

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/qZ8tD3/1

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/611103

PHP Usage:

```
$wordlist = array('http','pic');
 $replaceWith  = "";

/* Sample data */
$words = 'This tweet has a pic.twitter.com/00GeQ3zLub and a url http://www.mywebsite.com';

foreach ($wordlist as $v)
  $words = clean($v, $words, $replaceWith);

function clean($word, $value, $replaceWith) {
    return preg_replace("/\S*$word\S*/i", "$replaceWith ",trim($value));
}

echo $words;
```

Comment: BINGO! This did it. Thank you soooo much!

Comment: One last shot. This is adding an extra white space in the tweet in the second demo. How can I remove that?

Comment: That is because of the leading and trailing spaces on the URL. You could add horizontal spaces to the regex then add a space in. https://regex101.com/r/pA3aY9/2

Answer (score 1):

you can use this...

https://eval.in/611119

```
$wordlist = array('http','pic');
 $replaceWith  = "";



/* Sample data */
$words = 'This tweet has a pic.twitter.com/00GeQ3zLub and a url http://www.mywebsite.com';

foreach ($wordlist as $v)
  $words = clean($v, $words, $replaceWith);

function clean($word, $value, $replaceWith) {
    $reg_exUrl = "/ (".$word.")(\:\/\/|.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/ ";
    return preg_replace($reg_exUrl,$replaceWith,trim($value));

}

echo $words;
?>
```

Comment: I like this. I noticed tho, it's adding an extra "white space" in the tweet. How would we remove that?

Comment: Thanks so much Arvind!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you trim `$value` first thing, then use a function like this:

```
function clean($word, $value, $replaceWith) {
    $scan = preg_quote($word);
    return preg_replace("#\\S{$scan}\\S#i", $replaceWith . ' ', $value);
}
```

This requires $value to contain a whitespace at beginning and end, so you can:

```
$value = " {$value} ";
foreach ($words as $word) {
    $value = clean($word, $value, $replaceWith);
}
$value = trim($value);
```

You could also `preg_split` $value around whitespaces and use `array_filter` on the resulting array, but this solution could be less performant.

As an optimization, if all words have the same replacement, then you can assemble a single regex out of the words array:

```
// So [ 'http', '.pic' ] becomes '#\\S(http|\\.pic)\\S#i'
$regex = '#\\S(' 
       . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $words))
       . ')\\S#i';

$value = trim(preg_replace($regex, $replaceWith . ' ', " {$value} "));
```